# Force EllipticTheta to "use" $(e^{\pi i\tau})^{\lambda}=e^{\pi i\tau \lambda}$

Tags: functions, function-construction, special-functions

Define $\theta_2 (q)=2\sum_{n\ge 0}q^{(n+1/2)^2}$ and $\theta_3 (q)=1+2\sum_{n\ge 1}q^{n^2}$, $q=e^{\pi i\tau}$, $q^{\lambda}=e^{\pi i\tau \lambda}$, $q\in\mathbb{C}$, $|q|\lt 1$, $\tau\in\mathbb{C}$, $\operatorname{Im}\tau\gt 0$, $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}$.

Then
$$\theta_2^2(q^2)=\theta_3^2(q)-\theta_3^2(q^2)$$
[for all](https://dlmf.nist.gov/20.7#v) $q\in\mathbb{C}$, $0\lt |q|\lt 1$.

However, Mathematica's `EllipticTheta[2,0,q]` and `EllipticTheta[3,0,q]` do not satisfy the above identity for all complex $q$ when $0\lt |q|\lt 1$. This is caused by the fact that Mathematica doesn't "use" $(e^{\pi i\tau})^{\lambda}=e^{\pi i\tau\lambda}$ in this context (using this is usual in the literature). Instead, it evaluates $e^{\pi i\tau}$ and then this is raised to the $\lambda$. In other words, it should be true that
$$\theta_2^2 (e^{2\pi i\tau})=\theta_3^2(e^{\pi i\tau})-\theta_3^2(e^{2\pi i\tau})$$
for all $\tau\in\mathbb{C}$ and $\operatorname{Im}\tau\gt 0$ but this is not in accordance with Mathematica's EllipticTheta functions: Mathematica interprets $\theta_2(e^{\pi i\tau})$ as $\theta_2 (e^{\pi i\tau})=2\sum_{n\ge 0} (e^{\pi i\tau})^{(n+1/2)^2}$ instead of $\theta_2(e^{\pi i\tau})=2\sum_{n\ge 0}e^{\pi i\tau (n+1/2)^2}$, which doesn't always give the same result.

Can `EllipticTheta[2,0,q]` in Mathematica be "redefined" in some way such that this identity (and a lot of others) holds true? Instead of $q\mapsto \theta_2(q)$, I want to define $\tau\mapsto \theta_2(e^{\pi i\tau})$. But using `f[t_]:=EllipticTheta[2,0,E^(Pi I t)]` causes some [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/) identities to fail due to the above problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Functions Wolfram site](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticTheta2/27/01/01/02/0001/) we get

```
EllipticTheta[2, z, q] == (q^(1/4) EllipticTheta[3, z
   - (Pi/2) τ, q])/ E^(I z) /; q == E^(I Pi τ)
```

So define a new theta `Th2` and test the identity with the code

```
Th2[z_, tau_] := With[{q=E^(I Pi tau)}, E^(I Pi tau/4)
    EllipticTheta[3, z - (Pi/2) tau, q]/ E^(I z)];
test1[tau_] := With[{q=E^(I Pi tau)}, {Th2[0, 2tau]^2,
    EllipticTheta[3,0,q]^2 - EllipticTheta[3,0,q^2]^2}];
ComplexPlot[(#1 - #2&)@@test1[tau], {tau,-4+.1I, 4+4I}]
```